# Compare two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare two csv files to look for common values in column 1.

```
import csv

f_d1 = open('test1.csv')
f_d2 = open('test2.csv')

f1_csv = csv.reader(f_d1)
f2_csv = csv.reader(f_d2)

for x,y in zip(f1_csv,f2_csv):
    print(x,y)
```

I am trying to compare x[0] with y[0]. I am fairly new to python and trying to find the most pythonic way to achieve the results. Here is the csv files.

test1.csv

```
Hadrosaurus,1.2
Struthiomimus,0.92
Velociraptor,1.0
Triceratops,0.87
Euoplocephalus,1.6
Stegosaurus,1.4
Tyrannosaurus Rex,2.5
```

test2.csv

```
Euoplocephalus,1.87
Stegosaurus,1.9
Tyrannosaurus Rex,5.76
Hadrosaurus,1.4
Deinonychus,1.21
Struthiomimus,1.34
Velociraptor,2.72
```

Comment: What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: You mean column 1? The name or the number?

Comment: I am trying to output the list of common items in column 1. For example, the output will be the list with all values but 'Deinonychus' as it is not in test2.csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are not prohibitively large, you can read both of them with a CSV reader, convert the first columns to sets, and calculate the set intersection:

```
with open('test1.csv') as f:
   set1 = set(x[0] for x in csv.reader(f))
with open('test2.csv') as f:
   set2 = set(x[0] for x in csv.reader(f))
print(set1 & set2)
#{'Hadrosaurus', 'Euoplocephalus', 'Tyrannosaurus Rex', 'Struthiomimus', 
#  'Velociraptor', 'Stegosaurus'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the set intersection:

```
import csv

f_d1 = open('test1.csv')
f_d2 = open('test2.csv')

f1_csv = csv.reader(f_d1)
f2_csv = csv.reader(f_d2)

x = set([item[0] for item in f1_csv])
y = set([item[0] for item in f2_csv])

print(x & y)
```

Comment: I based my code off yours, but @DYZ's code is more succinct and Pythonic than what I wrote, so in the future you might want to emulate their style.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to test whether the numerical values in each row are the same. You can modify this to test whether, for instance, the values are within some distance of each other:

```
import csv

f_d1 = open('test1.csv')
f_d2 = open('test2.csv')

f1_csv = csv.reader(f_d1)
f2_csv = csv.reader(f_d2)

for x,y in zip(f1_csv,f2_csv):
    if x[1] == y[1]:
        print('they match!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the `defaultdict` in Python and you can iterate both the files and maintain the count in a dictionary like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for row in f1_csv:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])

for row in f2_csv:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])

d = {k: d[k] for k in d if len(d[k]) > 1}

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
    {'Hadrosaurus': ['1.2', '1.4'], 'Struthiomimus': ['0.92', '1.34'], 'Velociraptor': ['1.0', '2.72'], 
'Euoplocephalus': ['1.6', '1.87'], 'Stegosaurus': ['1.4', '1.9'], 'Tyrannosaurus Rex': ['2.5', '5.76']}
```