# Comparing two CSV files and print the difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to compare CSV files, I have 2 CSV Files - CSVFileOne, CSVFileTwo.
my desired output is printing CSVFileOne but only the rows that not existing in CSVFileTwo.

My code:

```
input_file = CSVFileOne
ABGSOne = []
with open(input_file, encoding='UTF-8') as fone:
    rowsOne = csv.reader(fone,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rowsOne, None)
    for rowOne in rowsOne:
        abbgone = {}
        abbgone['astringOne'] = row[0]
        abbgone['bstringOne'] = row[1]
        abbgone['cstringOne'] = row[2]
        abbgone['dstringOne'] = row[3]
        ABGSOne.append(abbgone)



input_fileTwo = CSVFileTwo
ABGSTwo = []
with open(input_fileTwo, encoding='UTF-8') as ftwo:
    rowsTwo = csv.reader(ftwo,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rowsTwo, None)
    for rowTwo in rowsTwo:
        abbgtwo = {}
        abbgtwo['astringTwo'] = row[0]
        abbgtwo['bstringTwo'] = row[1]
        abbgtwo['cstringTwo'] = row[2]
        abbgtwo['dstringTwo'] = row[3]
        ABGSOne.append(abbgTwo)



for abbgone in ABGSOne:
   if abbgone['bstringOne'] == abbgtwo['bstringTwo']:
        print('abbgone['bstringOne']
```

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030713/compare-two-csv-files

Answer (score 0):

try this out .

```
with open('CSVFileOne.csv', 'r') as t1, open('CSVFileTwo.csv', 'r') as t2:
fileone = t1.readlines()
filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('Desired.csv', 'w') as outFile:
for line in filetwo:
    if line not in fileone:
        outFile.write(line)
```